# Does DataGridView crash when enough items is added that it expands beyond the window?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which I populate with values as soon as they are returned from an Udp-server. When there are only a few values my program works, but if enough values are retrieved that the dialogbox needs to expand outside the dialogbox, the DataGridView freezes.

I've created this simple method for populating the DataGrid.

```
public void populateGrid(string[] data)
        {
            dataGrid.Rows.Add(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how or why, but by creating a backgroundworker and invoking a delegate on the DGV I accomplished adding items without the system freezing, and the backgroundworker reaches it's Completed event.

Answer (score 0):

The Winforms DataGridView should indeed be able to expand easily beyond what's visible. One of the programs I wrote routinely has thousands of items in some of its DGVs, and DGVs are used everywhere in that software. I populate the lists using the Rows.Add() method, not unlike what you're doing.

The question becomes, how are you using this populateGrid method? Are you looping through calls, or are you using controls with user-entered data to form the array for each row? How is the GridView set up (readonly? Can the user add/delete rows?) Are there events to respond to resizing of DGV elements? Are you "lazy-loading" the records from some data source to populate this DGV?

Try attaching the debugger and hitting the "pause" button to see where the system is hanging. You may see repetitions in the call stack indicating an infinite loop of event handlers, or it may be hanging on a method call you expected to be fast but is waiting for a troublesome data source or pulling MUCH more info than you need.

Comment: Thanks KeithS - I'll try attaching the debugger. When I open the form containing the DGV I open a connection to a Udp-server, the first message from the server is the number of items to expect, then the actual items, and then I close the connection. Do I have to 'close' the DGV for incoming data?

Comment: Well, understand that UDP is a stateless connection with little or no error-checking; you and the server are basically "shouting" at each other and hoping the other side heard and understood the message. If you expect 5 items, receive 4, and one is lost or damaged in transit, you could easily wait forever for the last one because the server didn't know you didn't get it, and you probably won't know which one you didn't get to ask for it again. Protocols like TCP have more robust message integrity features; the protocol's implementation will ask for replacements for lost or damaged packets.

Comment: I coundn't find anything that would cause the system to freeze up. I did not make the logic in a way that it would wait for the last message, I only use the expected package "number" to tell the user what to expect. By creating a backgroundworker and invoking a delegate on the DGV I accomplished adding items without the system freezing, and the backgroundworker reaches it's Completed event.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that the system was not freezing indefinitely. Yes, ALL data retrieval/population should occur in a background thread if possible; otherwise the application's main thread is busy adding rows to the DGV and cannot respond to the Windows message loop. For my implementation I set up a simple asynchronous model to grab data, then put it in the DGV in the async callback; there's not a great way to do population asynchronously because it affects a GUI object and therefore must be done on the GUI (main) thread.